# ffmpeg pipe images to redis

Tags: ffmpeg, redis

I need to find a way to save ffmpeg frames into redis variable.

Currently I'm piping png images from ffmpeg to redis but it concatenate all images:

ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:5545 -c:v png -r 1 -update 1 - | redis-cli -x HSET sb4up

Is it possible to update the redis variable with a new frame every second?

Comment: There may be a way without writing too much *"glue"* code to join the various parts together, but if some code were needed what language(s) would be acceptable? Does your video stream contain transparency or is there some reason for selecting PNG format?

Comment: python, bash scripting, would be fine. there is not a specific reason for png, could also be jpeg. I saw that ffmpeg supports mq output, maybe there is also a kind of redis plugin... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having a think about this. I am no expert in `ffmpeg` and there may be something much simpler, so if someone makes me aware of a better method I will likely delete this.

For the moment, my thought is that if `ffmpeg` writes JPEG or PNG as output, you need a tool that is able to parse a concatenated stream and search for START-OF-IMAGE/END-OF-IMAGE or  (JPEG SOI/EOI or PNG IHDR/IEND) markers and understand chunks and sections. So, I thought it might be simpler to force `ffmpeg` to write fixed length images, then you can just read `N` bytes knowing it corresponds to a frame and you don't need a bunch of *"glue"* code to write and maintain - just standard tools.

I don't have your UDP stream, so I just used a `.mov` file. I then forced `RGB24` encoding and a fixed size, resized frame of 640x480. I then split that into chunks of 640x480x3 RGB bytes and ask **ImageMagick** to create a PNG from the raw video and whack it into Redis as a PNG:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set height and width of frame, and size in bytes
h=480
w=640
bytes=$((h*w*3))

ffmpeg -i video.mov -r 1 -s ${w}x${h} -update 1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo - 2> /dev/null | \
   gsplit -b $bytes --filter="magick -depth 8 -size ${w}x${h} rgb:- png:- | redis-cli -x SET sb4up"
```

I then use **OpenCV** to grab the image every 0.5 seconds from **Redis** and display the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import redis
import cv2
import numpy as np

host='localhost'
port=6379
        
r = redis.Redis(host,port)

while True:
   png=r.get('sb4up')
   frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(png,np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   cv2.imshow("Viewer", frame)
   cv2.waitKey(500)
```

**Note**: I used `gsplit` for GNU `split` because I am on a Mac. On Linux, just use `split`.

**Note**: Obviously you can use a differently sized frame as long as you update it in both parts of the code - i.e. both in `gsplit` and **ImageMagick**.

**Note**: You don't necessarily need to install **ImageMagick** and PNG-encode each image, because you will only have the one, single, latest image in **Redis** so space will not be an issue as there are not thousands of frames, so you could omit **ImageMagick** and just write the raw RGB24 data into **Redis** without **ImageMagick**. Then grab the raw data from **Redis** and use `np.reshape()` to make it into a correctly-shaped image.

I am still thinking and may come up with something better... **Perl** might be good for splitting a binary stream on a pattern...

Another idea is to have `ffmpeg` write `PNG` files with a sequential number like `frame-%03d.png` and run `fswatch/inotify` to grab the individual frames and stuff them into **Redis**.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason. I got the urge to write some **Python** to split a continuous stream of concatenated PNG files and send each one to **Redis** as it arrives.

The program reads a stream of PNG files in [PNG chunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#%22Chunks%22_within_the_file), rather than in 1MB blocks and looking for `IEND` markers which would result in a 30 image delay if your individual PNG images were 33kB each in size. Each PNG chunk has a *"chunk size"* (4 bytes in network byte order) and a *"chunk type"* (4 bytes). The first chunk is the 8-byte signature and the last one in an image is the `IEND` chunk. As chunks arrive they are read and gathered in a `bytearray` called `wholePNG`. When the end of the PNG arrives, I send this to **Redis**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
################################################################################
# pngsplit - split a concatenated stream of PNG files
# Mark Setchell
################################################################################

import redis
import os, sys
from struct import unpack

# Ensure stdin is binary
fp = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb')

# Connect to Redis
host='localhost'
port=6379
r = redis.Redis(host,port)

# Define a valid PNG signature
validSig = bytes.fromhex('89504e470d0a1a0a')
expectingSig = True

while True:
   # We expect an 8-byte PNG signature at the start of each PNG file
   if expectingSig:
      # Get signature and ensure it is a PNG signature
      rawSig = fp.read(8)
      if len(rawSig) != 8:
         break
      if rawSig != validSig:
         print('ERROR: Not a valid PNG signature', file=sys.stderr)
         sys.exit(1)
      expectingSig = False
      # Start building a new PNG to send to Redis
      wholePNG = bytearray(validSig)

   # Read 4 bytes and extract PNG chunk length
   rawChunkLength = fp.read(4)
   chunkLen  = unpack('!I', rawChunkLength)[0]
   wholePNG += rawChunkLength

   # Read 4 bytes and extract PNG chunk type
   rawChunkType = fp.read(4)
   b0,b1,b2,b3 = unpack('BBBB', rawChunkType)
   chunkType = chr(b0) + chr(b1) + chr(b2) + chr(b3)
   print(f'DEBUG: {chunkType} PNG chunk, length={chunkLen}')
   wholePNG += rawChunkType

   # Read the chunk data
   if chunkLen > 0:
      rawData = fp.read(chunkLen)
      wholePNG += rawData

   # Read the CRC
   rawCRC = fp.read(4)
   wholePNG += rawCRC

   # If IEND chunk
   if chunkType == 'IEND':
      print('DEBUG: Received IEND chunk - sending to Redis')
      r.set('sb4up', bytes(wholePNG))
      # I guess we are now expecting a new PNG
      expectingSig = True
```

You can run it like this:

```
ffmpeg command producing PNG stream | ./pngsplit.py
```

and it will send each PNG to Redis as `sb4up` as it arrives.

I tested it like this in a directory with a load of random PNG images:

```
while : ; do cat *.png; done | ./pngsplit.py
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, ffmpeg, video, stream, split, PNG chunk, concatenate.